# Carousel type of slide between two divs

Tags: jquery, slider

I am trying to have two div cards showing in a carousel manner. A user is presented with a card with a graph view with. The card also has a button for more info; when he clicks in the info button the card should slide to the right of the screen and disappear, while a card containing the supporting info should shows from the left of the screen.

sorry for the lack of knowledge in advance

here's is what I have written.

HTML:

```
            <div id="userNav" class="box -width--4of4">
                <div class="data-card">
                    <button id="loginPanel" class="button -fill--transparent -is--icon pull-right"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></button>
                  <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 20px auto"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JQuery:

```
 $('#loginPanel').click(function(){

            if ($('#userNav').is(':hidden')) {

               $('#userNav').show('slide',{direction:'left'},1000);
            } else {

               $('#userNav').hide('slide',{direction:'left'},1000);
            }
});


$('#loginPanel1').click(function(){

            if ($('#userNav').is(':hidden')) {

               $('#userNav').show('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
            } else {

               $('#userNav').hide('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
            }
});
```

Comment: I'm seeing classes .pull-right and also the use of Font Awesome. Are we using Bootstrap, per chance?

Comment: I am yes @jswebb

Comment: Check out my answer below and let me know if that is what you're thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the two cards in a container, set it to `position: relative;` and make the cards absolutely positioned. Then you could create specific classes for the cards to simulate animation, changing position and opacity of each element simultaneously over a set duration.

This can be achieved in several different ways, but here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33s6moxn/1/) showing the basic concept.

**EDIT**: Fiddle updated to reflect commented concerns.

Comment: By changing the position to relative, the other divs mount on top of these ones. Also, I loose the styling I had on the card. Maybe if I put it in a different section of my page; though I would still have the issue with the styling no applying.

Comment: By default, `div` fits its content; however, since all of its content is pulled out of the page flow, the container collapses. To fix this, you just have to explicitly set a width for the container div. See the updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/33s6moxn/1/).

Comment: Regarding the styling: I can't help because you didn't supply the CSS, so I don't know how you're styling the DOM elements. Remember that order matters when writing CSS, from top to bottom, along with specificity of selectors.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you for the lesson. Quick question. I intend to maintain the styling I have on the div, but even by altering the css you posted, the div does not look the same; anything you can share on this?

Comment: Glad I could help! If you could, mark this as selected answer, as that helps with search filters. As for your current styles: ultimately it is going to depend largely on how you currently have elements set up. As I cannot see the CSS, I cannot see how the styling applied in this exercise conflicts with your current approach. Please open a new question with a CSS tag, as it is a styling and not a jQuery-related inquiry. Then, post your relevant HTML, CSS and scripts and I and others can help you.